# Update table with new checkbox values overriding the old ones

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write simplest code for updating checkbox values using only mysql.

**Existing example of database with some predefined values:**

```
id | checked
----------
1  | 1
2  | 0
3  | 1
```

**HTML:**

*Generated HTML with existing database values, which are later modified by user and updated.*

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[1]" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[2]">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[3]" checked="checked">
```

POST returns only array of id's which **are** checked, not all of them (excluding the ones with "off" value).

Now, i would like to update the whole table, but like i said, I can only operate with checked (on) values.

My initial though was to update the whole table with 'checked' = 0 and later set back all the id's which i keep in array to 'checked' = 1.

```
UPDATE -> set all to 0
UPDATE -> set checked (values from array) to 1
```

**Is there a more elegant one query solution to achieve this?**

*I am aware of option of first selecting all the id's, comparing them with new array in php and later updating, but would like to avoid that.*

Comment: Unfortunately yea, only selected checkboxes get posted. Your idea is fine to just update all to 0 and then update selected to 1.

Comment: But do it as a transaction, such that if the second query fails then the first query fails too.

Comment: Alternatively, have a hidden initial value(s) , which can be overwritten - but I like your method better

Comment: @Strawberry yes hidden values are also an option, but i always prefer as few user modifiable options as possible. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a conditional `UPDATE` operation, like this:

```
// When first and third checkboxe is checked
UPDATE checkbox_table SET checked = CASE WHEN id IN (1,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Or

```
// When second and third checkbox is checked
UPDATE checkbox_table SET checked = CASE WHEN id IN (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Like that...

An **example** would be like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[1]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[2]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[3]">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP:**

After form submission get the selected checkbox values using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function and then perform the conditional `UPDATE` operation.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['check'])){
        $checked_keys = array_keys($_POST['check']);
        $query = "UPDATE checkbox_table SET checked = CASE WHEN id IN (" . implode(',', $checked_keys) . ") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
    }else{
        $query = "UPDATE checkbox_table SET checked = 0";
    }
    // Now execute this $query
}
```

Comment: Interesting :) can i add other WHERE conditions after END as normal?

Comment: @devbull yes, you can also put `WHERE` clause after `END`.